# Why does fabric report "No hosts found"?

Tags: python, fabric

```
env.roledefs = {
    'seed': ['host1'],
    'peer': ['host2']
}

@roles('seed')
def test():
    pass

@roles('peer')
def test1():
    pass

def deploy():
    test()
    test1()
```

fab test, fab test1 - all ok

fab deploy:

No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Why ?

Comment: did the execute thing help? I still get this issue even wrapping the calls in deploy in execute

Comment: AHHH! i was doing execute(test_task()) not execute(test_task) !!! nvmd

Answer (score 4):

When calling `test` and `test1` from `deploy`, the `@roles` are not taken into account. You should call the functions using `execute(test)` and `execute(test1)`.

See also:

- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute
- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute

Comment: Even wrapped in execute, it still complains for me. why?

Answer (score 1):

Because env.hosts is not set. Your test() functions do not use run() or any similar command that requires ssh connection, while deploy(), presumably, does().

Read these first:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/usage/env.html#hosts

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/usage/execution.html#hosts